# Floating Ads Popping Up On Screen

Tags: ads, popup, samsung-galaxy-note-8

As of a couple of days ago, I've been noticing a particular floating ad on my screen. It keeps popping up occasionally. 
I've googled it and have removed the apps I've installed in the last couple of days as per the instructions, but it's still present.

Please find a screenshot below.

[image: IMG:]

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to hunt the cause using [AppWatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tafayor.appwatch)

Comment: @beeshyams I'm using that right now but it's not working.

Comment: Look at what each app can do, permissions wise. Look for the ones that have permission to display things above other apps. This will narrow your search down. Then you just have to do a process of elimination to determine which app is the culprit. That is how I would go about it, anyway. You can block all the apps from doing that, then allow one app at a time to have that permission back, run it for a while, then allow the next.